# Return one item of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

There is an input in which there should be several additional attributes to help the user
I can insert these attributes, but the redux form will return a whole line, and I only need an email, how to make it return only email

```js
  <Field component={SelectUser} name="SendTo" validate={[required]} id="age-native-simple">
          <option value="" />
          {
          props.initialValues.users.map((p, index) => (
<option key={index}>{p.FIO+" "+p.Email+" "+p.Otdel}</option>
          ))}
        </Field>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
  <Field component={SelectUser} name="SendTo" validate={[required]} id="age-native-simple">
          <option value="" />
          {
          props.initialValues.users.map((p, index) => (
<option value={p.Email} key={index}>{p.FIO+" "+p.Email+" "+p.Otdel}</option>
          ))}
        </Field>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an array by splitting the string by white space, and return 4th element, given that it's always in the same position.